# Boot repair fails to repair my dual boot (ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

Usually when I start my laptop, grub starts and allows me to boot either ubuntu or windows. 
However, after a windows update yesterday, windows is started automatically and selecting ubuntu in the boot options doesn't work either. The .efi files (grub64.efi and shim.efi) do show up in that menu, but the system tells me, that there's something wrong with them.

I tried using the Boot Repair tool via a bootable USB, but that didn't help. 
Here are the infos from Boot Repair: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11302920/

I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: What motherboard / computer do you have?

Comment: It's a HP EliteBook 820 G1

Comment: Checkout this (it's for a 840 which is very similar to the 820 - replace "archlinux" with "ubuntu"): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_EliteBook_840_G1#Using_the_.22Customized_Boot.22_path_option_.28recommended.29

Comment: I already came across this, but how do I find out the correct path to the .efi file? I tried with efi\ubuntu\grubx64.efi and -\shimx64.efi, but that wasn't the right one

Comment: Check out the directory /boot/efi they should be there.

Comment: thanks a lot. Apparently I forgot to put the \ before EFI....